# .htaccess - how to redirect from root to subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website with URL www.somedomain.com

I want to redirect to a subfolder "folder", so that when you enter the website you are automatically redirected to www.somedomain.com/subfolder.

But I do not want the root directory to be changed, just simple redirection.

Is this possible with .htaccess ?

Is it possible to hide the /subfolder part from the URL also ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rewrite rule that uses ^$ to represent the root and rewrite that to your /store directory, like this:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /store [L]

Just replace store with your directory